# Is it possible to construct a multi-colored double-bladed lightsaber?

Tags: star-wars, lightsaber, weapon

I was just watching [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AmR5LoyZ4jw) video of some SW dueling at the 2015 World Fencing Championship, and wondered if it's actually possible in the SW universe to construct a multi-colored double-bladed lightsaber?

Are there any accounts of such a thing? If not, would it at least be theoretically possible to make one, or, are there obvious limitations?

Comment: The lightsaber in the video is basically two regular lightsabers joined at the end. (I was hoping for something a little more exciting, like a rainbow blade...)

Comment: A dual-bladed lightsaber is simply two lightsabers attached to each other. There's the implication that the may share a power-source, but given that Maul's worked when one half was removed, it may be that the power-sources are simply pressed together and not shared; https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/starwars/images/4/41/KunLightsaberSchematic.jpg/revision/latest/scale-to-width-down/640?cb=20110717211606

Comment: To the best of my knowledge no such things exists in canon. It would be theoretically possible

Comment: I think it may be possible, but it has not been seen. The lightsaber color as far as I know currently in canon is determined by the crystal, which starts out colorless and is influenced to be a certain color as the padawan goes through training. This is different than at the start where a color was just dependent upon a certain colored crystal. Either way, the only way I could see two colors on a single saber would be to incorporate two separate crystals of different colors into the construction

Comment: @Laurel - A rainbow blade of some sort would be pretty cool... I am envisioning an "Inside Out" situation inside the crystal happening haha

Comment: @Laurel In Legends, there do exist rainbow gems, which can be used as saber crystals. ..would be wicked to see one in action and how it pulsates.

Comment: The *Knights of the Old Republic* and *Jedi Knight: Jedi Academy* games have one lightsaber crystal determine the color for both ends of a double-bladed lightsaber. It's not clear to me if that's simply a gameplay simplification or how it works in-universe.

Comment: Disappointed, I'd hoped lightsaber duelling was an actual worldwide fencing competitive category, not just a choreographed show.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

According to the [Star Wars Database](http://www.starwars.com/databank/darth-mauls-lightsaber), Maul's double-sided lightsaber was just two standard ones joined together.

> The Sith apprentice Darth Maul wielded a double-bladed lightsaber made by joining two hilts together end-to-end.

This makes sense, as the lightsaber continues to function once cut in half.

[image]

Therefore, two lightsabers with different-colored crystals could easily be combined to form a double-bladed lightsaber.

Answer (score 5):

As [Rogue Jedi](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/51226/rogue-jedi) says, Maul's double-bladed saber is essentially two regular sabers. It has two of every necessary component for a lightsaber to function, which means there are probably two kyber crystals in there. If he were to swap them out, he could get practically any combination of lightsaber colors there is. So if you have a saber similar to Maul's saber, you can definitely get a multi-colored double-bladed lightsaber. My source to back up my statement of his saber having two of every component is *Star Wars: The Visual Encyclopedia*, published by DK US, authors are Tricia Barr, Adam Bray, and Cole Horton (not the elephant).

Comment: I apologize if this answer possibly goes against the rules in that it is quite similar to Rogue Jedi's answer, but I was just making the answer more clear to anyone who understands it well enough. At least no one has commented about that... yet...

Answer (score 1):

**If you want to be attuned to weapon then no.**

Reason for that is simple - [Kyber crystals](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Kyber_crystal) were sort of Force sensitive. Each Jedi would select (and be selected by) one matching his own personality. Therefore, crystals would become green, blue, and in some rarer instances violet, white or yellow. Sith and other darksiders would bleed crystal and it will become red . So, even those who constructed weapons made of two crystals (Maul, Temple Guards etc...) would have both blades in same color.

Both Jedi and Sith would build their own lightsabers using the Force, therefore it could be implied that they would have to be attuned to Kyber crystals in question to achieve this. Of course, I assume it would be possible to somehow join two already existing sabers into one saberstaff, but I doubt this weapon would be of sufficient quality.

Comment: Why wouldn't simply attaching two sabers together be sufficient?

Comment: @Valorum If you read recent comics about Vader, there were whole lot of explanation why his blue lightsaber was not good enough for him as it was weapon of Jedi, and why he needs to construct new one (red) .

Comment: I think this is answering a slightly different question so I tried to ask it.
https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/183540/does-the-kyber-crystal-used-in-lightsabers-have-an-effect-on-the-user