# Does the kyber crystal used in a lightsaber have an effect on the user?

Tags: star-wars, lightsaber

Is there any evidence of a force user using a kyber crystal that is wrong for them in their lightsaber and this having an effect on their ability to use it? How does it impact them?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Not in any significant way. In fact, it's just the opposite. In current canon, the crystal is affected by the user.

In the novel *Ahsoka*, she takes the kyber crystals from an Inquisitor's lightsaber and puts them in her hilts. They then changed color in response to her attunement.

> Before she could even consider shouting a warning, the red lightsaber burst into a mess of noise and light. Bright spots pricked at her eyes, and then all was quiet. The creature wasn’t going to bother her anymore.
>
> [...]
>
> Kneeling beside her fallen foe, Ahsoka sifted through the wreckage of his lightsaber hilt. The crystals that had powered his lightsaber were no longer contained by metal, but their song had not dimmed. She held them in one hand, almost shaking as the familiarity of them coursed through her, while the other hand retrieved the half-finished hilts she carried with her.
>
> [...]
>
> Her mind’s eye sorted the preassembled components and those she had just retrieved into order, locking each into place with the others. When Ahsoka opened her hands, she was not surprised to find that two lightsabers, rough and unfinished, were waiting.
>
> They would need more work, but they were hers.
>
> When she turned them on, they shone the brightest white.
>   <sub>*Ahsoka - Chapter 28*</sub>

The novel hints at the crystals being Ahsoka's which shows that even though they were wrong for the Inquisitor, it did not have a noticeable effect. And once Ahsoka got them, she was able to "reattune" them.

The Star Wars Databank says:

> A lightsaber crystal is colorless until first attuned and connected to a Jedi -- at which times it glows either blue or green or, in some rare instances, another shade. From that point on, it retains that hue.
>   <sub>[Kyber Crystal | Star Wars Databank](http://www.starwars.com/databank/lightsaber-crystal)</sub>

So all evidence points to the crystal being the only one affected. Now, since in current canon a crystal is attuned with the Force and an extension of a Force-sensitive's awareness, it is likely that using a crystal that is not yours (or using someone else's lightsaber) has some disadvantages. But this would be much like using any weapon that was not the one you were used to using.

In summary: The crystal will work and there will be little to no effect

Comment: In addition to this red lightsabers are "hurt" crystals ("mentally broken") as shown in the canon vader comics.

Answer (score 6):

**If the crystal is not attuned to user, he could not use it to full effect**

First example is from comic [Darth Vader: Dark Lord of the Sith part 1](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_Darth_Vader:_Dark_Lord_of_the_Sith). I could not copy all relevant pages here, but basically Palpatine tells Vader that his old blue saber is no longer good enough for him because it was Jedi weapon. Instead he needs to bleed Kyber crystal and build new one . It is implied that he lost his fight vs Kenobi because he was no longer attuned to the weapon.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Second example could be Luke Skywalker. He firstly used that same blue lightsaber (belonging to Anakin) but he was not very proficient with it, losing fight and hand vs Vader. Later, he constructed his own lightsaber (green) with much better results (beating both Vader and Jabba's henchmen)

Comment: A Jedi would construct their own blade after having first learned to use a standard blade. This would give them the knowledge needed to determine what unique features (more powerful emitter, shorter blade, lighter hilt, curved hilt, etc) would best suit their fighting style. I can't remember anything specific mentioned about the kyber affecting the finished product.

Comment: I'm pretty sure he lost his fight with Kenobi because he didn't have the high ground ;)

Comment: @Mwr247 Young fool, only now at the end do you understand ... red is high, and blue is low :P

Comment: @Valorum In new canon Jedi younglings would go to Ilum to select specific crystal for their lightsaber. Only after that they would become Padawans. This is in S05E06 of Clone Wars.

Comment: @rs.29 - Indeed, but I'm struggling to recall what's said about the crystal. They definitely need one but the rest of it (the whole choosing process) seems to just be part of a shared mystique rather than the crystal having any specific impact on the efficacy of the lightsaber.

Comment: @Valorum if my memory serves me, each youngling had to find his own crystal (out of many in the cave) , and latter with much effort construct lightsaber around it. Implying some kind of Force connection between weapon and wilder. As Jedi let Force guide them during duels, it is possible that with attuned weapon this Force guidance is stronger.

Comment: Do you not realize that Luke was much better trained in the Force and the ways of the Jedi and lightsaber combat by the time he fought Jabba's henchmen and fought Vader a second time? During his first fight with Vader, his training was not complete.

Comment: @DarthVader Not necessarily. Luke of course did have more experience, but he didn't have more formal training in lightsaber combat (in fact, he almost didn't have any lightsaber training at all) . His moves against Vader on Death Star 2  were clumsy, yet somehow more powerful. Of course, Disney could change all of that with their meddling, but it seems to me that both Vader and Emperor being impressed that Luke managed to create lightsaber meant that he is now more powerful exactly because of it (bond between him and lightsaber)